# Can I limit LinkedIn requests to second degree connections?

Tags: spam-prevention, linkedin

I get a number of LinkedIn requests from people I don't know, and who don't know anyone I know (i.e. they're not a 2nd degree connection). I have no idea who these people are, and the requests feel like spam (they never come with a personal greeting, or anything to suggest they're legitimate).

Is there a way to limit connection requests to 2nd degree connections so I stop getting this spam?

Answer (score 1):

You can control who can send you invitations.

From the [Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70):

> **Controlling Who Can Send You Invitations**
>
> You can select *who can send you invitations* from the **Communications** tab of the *Privacy & Settings* page. You'll receive a notification each time a LinkedIn member invites you to connect.
>
> Select one of the following preferences:
>
> 1. Anyone on LinkedIn (Recommended)
> 2. Only people who know your email address or appear in your "Imported Contacts" list
> 3. Only people who appear in your "Imported Contacts" list
>
> **Note:** If you select one of the last two options above, go to the Add Connections page to make sure your **Imported Contacts** list is up to date.
>
> Invitations that don't meet your preferences will appear in your blocked invitations list.

Comment: If you recognize any invitation as a spam, you can [report that invitation as spam](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37822/~/recognizing-and-reporting-spam).

Comment: That prevents 2nd degree connections who don't know my email address (or I theirs) from being able to connect.

Comment: Yes, there is no other way.